# Assets 2 select file on upload

Tags: assets

When I upgraded to Assets 2, I noticed that when uploading a file from the modal window in a channel entry form that once the file is uploaded, Assets doesn't automatically select it for me anymore. I have to do a search for the filename. Is that the normal behavior for Assets 2? Or am I the only one experiencing this? And, if it's just me, is there any way to solve it.

Here is a step-by-step list of the process:

1. Open either a new or existing channel entry form
2. In the Assets field, click **Add file**
3. In the Assets modal window, click **Upload files**
4. Locate file to upload from file system, then click **OK**
5. The file uploads
6. **this is what's not happening:** Assets automatically selects the just-uploaded file(s)
7. Double-click on the newly-uploaded file to add it to the Assets field

[image: screenshot of what Assets isn't doing]

**Here's a new/interesting discovery:** step 6 above **does** happen when I use a computer that is not on my organization's official network. I'm wondering if it's blocking a Javascript or something like that??

Currently running Assets 2.1, was running Assets 2.0.5, on EE 2.5.2 issue happens in both versions for me.

---

April 11, 2013

Screenshot of Javascript console errors
[image: screen shot of javascript console errors]

The Uncaught TypeError: Object... happened on page load, the Double-instantiating a select... happened (and I'm not really sure if it's an error or just logging) when Assets completes the file upload and selects the document.

Thanks!
- B

Comment: Hi, Brett - can you add to your original post the step by step clicks you're taking, and what the expected outcome is?  For instance, I went to a new channel entry and clicked "Add Files".  I chose some files and double clicked, and it added them to that custom field.  You're right that they weren't selected there.  You expect them to be highlighted at that point?  I may not be following quite what you are expecting to happen, so more details would help me to help you. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Lisa! Thanks for your quick reply. I've added the steps and a screen shot, plus an interesting tidbit I discovered. I'm not sure if you're notified once the original post is modified, so I thought I'd leave a comment, too.

Comment: Brett, that illustrates where I went wrong in trying to reproduce.  *blushes*  Thank you!  Hrm; are you familiar with your browser's dev console?  If you check that when doing this in your office, do you see any JS errors?  Also, have you tried a different browser in your office?

Comment: Hi Lisa! I did copy the two lines that appeared in Google Chrome's dev console. They are: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tablesorter' compressed.js:39
Double-instantiating a select on an element garnish-0.1.min.js:18

Comment: Also, we're limited to Chrome (most current version) and IE7 (hideous). I was using Chrome.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the error to your original post?  And you can't reproduce this anywhere but in your office?

Comment: Done! And, of course, when I add the file Assets auto-selects the file as expected. It may be some sort of enterprise IT policy that inconsistently blocks Javascript. I'm willing to accept that. And, no, I haven't been able to reproduce the error elsewhere.

Comment: Brett - if you want to email Super Admin details to support@pixelandtonic.com, I can test it on a Mac and PC from my home office and confirm your results.  It may also be worth re-uploading the Wygwam third_party and themes/third_party folders just to rule out any odd file corruption.

Comment: That does sound like corporate JS blocking in action. It seems that it can't find the tablesorter object. I've had many similar issues with other systems where things would stop working behind the firewall but would work fine in the DMZ. You can confirm if that script is being loaded by looking in the Chrome Web Insector > Elements > Frames > Scripts. You may very well see a red mark against that script indicating it's not being loaded.

Comment: Hi Lisa, did this progress other than putting it down to IT firewalls? We have the same problem and it's definitely not down to firewalls. We can reproduce, although not 100% consistently, on at least 3 different machines in different locations. I _think_ it works consistently when we upload large file sizes. When we do this the image is always selected and the pane scrolls to where the image sits in the thumb list. the problem doesn't seem to be the image being selected, it's more than the pane isn't always scrolled to the correct place where the newly uploaded image sits.

Comment: Running into the same issue with Assets 2.1.4 and ExpressionEngine 2.6.1. I feel like this was working before, but the client just reported that it isn't working now, which is sort of a pain for them because there are many files in the directory to which they're uploading.

The only error or warning I'm seeing is the same as noted above: Double-Instantiating a select on an element

Comment: I've just tested this in EE 2.5.5 and Assets 2.1.4 and noticed it's not working for me either. I hadn't even realised that the automatic selection was broken. No wonder a client recently pestered me about having to scroll all the way to the bottom of the list of files to select their most recently uploaded item (which is why I posted about that here: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13278/change-sort-order-of-files-in-assets-2/13454?noredirect=1)! Edit: Just seen this tweet: https://twitter.com/pixelandtonic/status/377257193575571456 There were 450 files in my directory.

Comment: This happened to me also. ExpressionEngine 2.5.3 and Assets 2.1.4. Looking forward to the fix in Assets 2.2

Comment: @JoshConner, Stephen, Ryan, did Assets 2.2+ fixed this for you?

Comment: After paying closer attention for the past few months, this appears to happen only in directories with hundreds of items (like our image uploads directory), in directories with fewer items, it works perfectly.

Comment: @Brett, have you officially reported this to Pixel and Tonic as a bug?

Comment: @Stephen I haven't, but I need to. I want to do actual tests of my hypothesis where I document the number of files in a directory, expected behavior and actual behavior. I'm also not using the most recent version of Assets. Once I upgrade, I'll test it out.

Answer (score 2):

We were seeing this same issue running Assets in our EE 2.5.2 environment. After we updated to Assets 2.2.2 it began working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I am having this same issue and have talked to P&T support about it. We isolated it down to a scenario in which the upload directory has a large number of images and the uploaded file falls somewhere below (out of range of) the images that are already displayed / loaded in the modal.

For example, if I upload an image with a name that starts with 0 or A, the image is highlighted as you would expect and the add button is available because it falls in the range of the displayed files. Conversely, if the file name starts with Z or some letter / number that is not already displayed in the modal then the image is not selected and the add button is not available so you have to manually search for the file or click on "Recently Uploaded."

This may not be the case for you but I thought I'd share it for anyone else that may be experiencing this issue.

Update: I have found that if I use List View in Assets, and then sort by newest first, the problem is solved. To help with this, I set List View as the default in the Channel Field settings.