# Change sort order of files in Assets 2

Tags: pixelandtonic, control-panel, assets

In Assets 2, is it possible to change the sort order of files so that it automatically shows the most recently uploaded files first? I was hoping there would be a setting or config override for this, but I can't seem to find one.

I've got lots of images in the Assets folders, and it'd be much more convenient to me (and save a lot of infinite scrolling - btw, pagination FTW!) if the most recently uploaded files appeared first. Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't mind knowing too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s the Date column in Table view – you can click on that to get files to sort by date (which defaults to the date uploaded).

Comment: I have suggested this as a workaround, but it's not ideal as you can barely see the images then, due to their small size. Also, the table view defaults on Name ascending rather than date descending so takes a few more clicks. I hoped that making the table view sort by most recently uploaded would remain sticky when clicking on the other views, but it's not. So I guess this has turned into a feature request.

Comment: Yeah I agree that Assets should remember that. Will add it to the 2.2 list. FYI there’s another feature coming in 2.2 that is also going to help you out with this, but I can’t talk about it :)

Comment: Sounds intriguing, and looking forward to it! :)